# Comparing two columns in pandas data frame and return difference

Tags: python, pandas, compare, string-comparison

I am comparing the content of two excel sheets that I have turned into a pandas data frame and placed the columns next to each other.

I have created some code that compares the two columns and gives the output below, but some of the strings contain large amounts of text so I would like to show **only** the difference.

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|         Old         |           New           |                   Changes                   |
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Apple, Egg, Ham     | Apple, Egg, Norway, Ham | Apple, Egg, Ham --> Apple, Egg, Norway, Ham |
| Instagram, Facebook | Instagram, Twitter      | Instagram, Facebook --> Instagram, Twitter  |
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

The optimal result would look something like this:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|         Old         |           New           |       Changes       |
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Apple, Egg, Ham     | Apple, Egg, Norway, Ham | +Norway             |
| Instagram, Facebook | Instagram, Twitter      | +Twitter, -Facebook |
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Norway has been added in row 1, Twitter has been added to row 2, and Facebook has been removed from row 2.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can the `old` and `new` column contain repeated values like `Apple, Egg, Ham, Apple`..? Or the values are always distinct?

Comment: The values are always distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to sets and then use their difference, also add `+` and `-` in `f-string`s and join by `,` in last step:

```
def f(x):
    old, new = set(x['Old'].split(', ')), set(x['New'].split(', '))
    d = old.difference(new)
    e = new.difference(old)
    return ', '.join([f'+{y}' for y in e] + [f'-{y}' for y in d])


df['Changes'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
                   Old                      New              Changes
0      Apple, Egg, Ham  Apple, Egg, Norway, Ham              +Norway
1  Instagram, Facebook       Instagram, Twitter  +Twitter, -Facebook
```

Comment: you beat me again in speed :)

Comment: o come on, I look up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I will go:

```
def find_diff(x):
    more = set(x.New.split(",")) - set(x.Old.split(","))
    less = set(x.Old.split(",")) - set(x.New.split(","))

    result = " ".join([f"+{x}" for x in more]) +", " + " ".join([f"-{x}" for x in less])
    return result

df.apply(find_diff, axis=1)
```

Comment: sorry, i did not see your answer. You were faster, like always

Comment: yop, it sometimes happens